# Laravel | Как объеденить 2 разных запроса в один

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, laravel

Как можно это сделать в одном запросе? Или объединить элементы в одну переменную
Именно не искать уже среди найденных а искать и так и так.

```
        $searchQuery = $request->validated()['search'];

        //$goods = Goods::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchQuery . '%')->paginate(15);
        $goods = Goods::whereHas('associations', function ($query) use ($searchQuery) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $searchQuery . '%');
        })->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```php
$goods = Goods::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchQuery . '%')
              ->orWhereHas('associations', function ($query) use ($searchQuery) {
                  $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $searchQuery . '%');
              })->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Чудесно! Спасибо!